# ThreadLocalRandom, генерация nextDouble(double, double)

Tags: java

Всем доброго времени суток.
Вопрос заключается в следующем: почему при объявлении в классе

```
private static Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
```

в методе следующего вида

```
public static double getPositiveDoubleRandomValue(double first, double second) {
    return random.nextDouble(first, second);
}
```

компилятор не предлагает использовать метод nextDouble(double, double), а единственно возможный вариант для использования - nextDouble()? Но в то же время, если реализацию метода изменить на

```
public static double getPositiveDoubleRandomValue(double first, double second) {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(first, second);
}
```

то все нормально работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае статическое поле `Random random` Инициализируется один раз каким-то потоком и все потоки которые будут далее обращаться к нему через метод `getPositiveDoubleRandomValue` будут использовать именно этот экземпляр объекта. В то время как идея `ThreadLocal` заключается в том что у каждого потока будет своя копия объекта `Random` и чтобы несколько потоков одновременно не полезли в один и тот же `Random`.

Во втором же варианте, поток, зайдя в метод, запросит свою копию `Random`, что позволит не допустить одновременного доступа двух потоко к одному объекту.

Intellij предупреждает вас что код получается не "Thread safe". Читайте "Не безопасным" и возможны очень странные ошибки и непредсказуемое поведение, если не исправить.